# Como fazer um sistema de pagamento via boleto?

Tags: php, boleto

Estou desenvolvendo uma loja online e estou com varias duvidas, mas a principal é:

> Como fazer um sistema de pagamento via boleto?

Nada mais é do que um sistema que gera um boleto valido, como o sistema do MercadoLivre.

Alguem sabe como se faz para gerar o boleto bancario valido?

OBS: Não ha nada ainda de codigo para fazer o pagamento.

Comment: Normalmente contra-se o serviço de um gateway de pagamentos ou diretamente com os bancos. Então você terá acesso a um webservice (API) por onde fará as transações como solicitar pagamento, emissão de fatura, etc.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em http://boletophp.com.br/

Comment: Lembrando que agora qualquer boleto tem que ser registrado

Comment: @JefersonAssis tem alguma informação concreta disso? Não tou tendo problema nenhum em receber meus boletos sem registro.

Comment: Daniel, pegue o manual de implementação do banco que vc tem conta, que lá tem tudo.

Comment: A Febraban decidiu acabar com os boletos sem registro, tem uma data certa para encerrar o recebimento de boleto sem registro, acho que inicio de 2017 (Não me recordo agora), dê uma buscada no google que você vai encontrar diversas notícias referente a isso

Comment: @JefersonAssis é que do jeito que você falou, deu impressão de ja ter parado. Essa coisa do registro vai dar muito pano pra manga ainda. Seguem as datas: Junho de 2015 Fim da oferta da cobrança sem registros para novos clientes (até esta data ainda dá pra contratar), Agosto de 2015 Início da operação da base centralizadora de benefícios, Dezembro de 2016 Término da migração das carteiras de cobrança sem registro para a modalidade registrada, Janeiro de 2017 Início da operação da base centralizadora de títulos. **Nota:** o sem registro continua sendo aceito depois, mas só no banco emissor.

Comment: Resta saber se os bancos vão criar vergonha e disponibilizar APIs menos enroladas para a comunicação. Arquivo de lote sem API padrão é muito arcaico.

Comment: Eles irão "diminuir" o aceite de sem registro e aumentar a taxa cobrada sem registro gradualmente, pelo menos no Bradesco, aqui no trabalho o pessoal esta implementando a forma de boleto com registro, antes era somente sem, e caso for emitido um boleto e pago sem registro a taxa será de R$ 10,00 isso com o passar do tempo irá aumentar, aconselho entrar em contato com o banco que será emitido para não ter surpresa depois que estiver tudo implementado, infelizmente é o lobby dos bancos para ganharem ainda mais dinheiro

Comment: @JefersonAssis tem uma coisa que eu gosto nisso: se cobrar por boleto, essas empresas que emitem boleto nao solicitado tipo mala direta vao gastar uma nota. Associação comercial de Pirapora do Pé do Judas, Clube Aquático da Misericórdia Molhada, e os famigerados registros ponto com da vida vao ter que gastar mais.

Comment: Estou reabrindo essa pergunta com base nesse tópico do meta: [Opiniões da comunidade sobre uma pergunta fechada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2515/3117), pois me parece ser uma situação semelhante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daniel, com o projeto opensource [boletophp](http://boletophp.com.br/) você consegue gerar boletos de quase todos os bancos, se eu não me engano no projeto é mais para boletos sem registro, mas com algumas modificações você consegue gerar boletos registrados também, com os boletos registrados você consegue até protestar a pessoa se ela não pagar.

Mas, mas saber se o boleto foi pago de fato, precisaria de alguma comunicação com o banco, coisa que nem todos os bancos fornecem.
Se você usar um gateway de pagamento isso é possível, segue alguns gateways de pagamento que suportam boleto e te informam quando o mesmo foi pago por meio de uma API:

https://www.adyen.com/br

http://www.braspag.com.br/

[https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/#rmcl)

https://www.paypal.com/br